# How to save shell command for next time use (Terminal of Android Studio)

Tags: android, terminal, macros

Suppose I run this command in Android Studio terminal

```
D:\.android\sdk\platform-tools/adb shell input text 'Some Text'
```

How do I save it (as macro) for next time use **After closing and opening Android Studio** instead of retyping the full command?

I know in the current session we can use the UP/DOWN arrows, I am looking at something like macros to be saved and be permanent...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and reduce my 80% time and effort to run shell command by creating `.bat` files with just one letter like `d.bat` etc (*single letter for reducing keyboard interaction to lessen time*).

If you have no idea about **What is bat file?** and **How to deal with it?** please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607586/7200133).

Comment: Thank you your response... This an old question and I gave up on using Android Studio..   But how your answer will solve the problem !! I'm talking about android studio macros and not about CMD prompt.. What I'm missing?