# How to add shortcut letters or words in Android Studio's Terminal for frequent commands?

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, command-prompt

In Android Studio's Terminal window, I use some commands too frequently and it's a lot frustrating.

The commands I use a thousand times a day are:

`adb kill-server`

`adb connect 192.168.43.1`

While Android Studio is not restarted yet, when you type these once, you can use `up` and `down` arrow keys to select them.

But the problem is that I restart AS or switch between projects so many times a day. And writing these commands over and over again is such a pain.

So I thought why don't we create one-letter shortcuts for these?!

For example, for the command `adb connect 192.168.43.1` I only want to type `c` and hit the Enter. And for the other one I want to type just `k`.

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1) Go to the root folder of `adb.exe`:

Hold Ctrl+Shift+Esc to open the Task Manager, and in the "Details" tab, right click on adb.exe and select "Open file location":
[image]

2) In that directory create a new Text Document and change its name to the shortcut letter you want and change the extension from `txt` to `bat`. i.e `k.bat`:

[image]

3) Now open the file in Notepad or just right click on it and select Edit, then type your command and save it and close it:

[image]

You can do the step 2 and 3 for other commands too. i.e `c.bat`, just be careful not to name them similar to already defined commands.

Now if you go back to the Terminal you can just write `k` or `c` and hit the Enter.

[image]